# Receive DEP0170 when connecting MongoDB Atlas with Node.js 20.3.1

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

Recently I updated Node.js to version 20.3.1 and tried to connect my MongoDB Atlas. When my Node.js's version is 19.X, the connection of Atlas is normal. However, The terminal shows the deprecation warning in the Node.js 20.3.1:

```bash
[DEP0170] DeprecationWarning: The URL mongodb://<USERNAME>:<PASSWORD>@ac-4hlp44x-shard-00-01.nqjamzn.mongodb.net:27017,ac-4hlp44x-shard-00-02.nqjamzn.mongodb.net:27017,ac-4hlp44x-shard-00-00.nqjamzn.mongodb.net:27017/<DATABASE>?authSource=admin&replicaSet=atlas-g8a2vr-shard-0&retryWrites=true&w=majority&ssl=true is invalid. Future versions of Node.js will throw an error.
```

The original url for connecting to the Altas is:

```
MONGODB_URI=mongodb+srv://<USERNAME>:<PASSWORD>@<USERNAME>.nqjamzn.mongodb.net/<DATABASE>?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

The database is still connected.

I tried to search the related articles, but there's not any information about this deprecation.

How can I fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Node 20 doesn't think mongodb atlas url is valid. There is nothing you can do other than waiting either mongodb or nodejs team fix this.

Answer (score 4):

I am seeing the same thing and looking at the node depreciation docs (https://nodejs.org/api/deprecations.html#DEP0170), it implies that it doesn't like non-number ports. I think therefore as the Mongo Atlas connection string tends to contain lots of ':' characters (e.g. `mongodb+srv://<USERNAME>:<PASSWORD>`), it thinks that these are supposed to be port numbers.

Not sure on the resolution yet but hopefully this helps.

Comment: answer that are easy to read and understand usually earn more points.
Please add more info and structure your answer using the instruction on the column on the right

Comment: It's pretty clear from his answer what the problems is Ion.  DEP0170: Invalid port when using url.parse()#
History
Type: Runtime

url.parse() accepts URLs with ports that are not numbers. This behavior might result in host name spoofing with unexpected input. These URLs will throw an error in future versions of Node.js, as the WHATWG URL API does already.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem this is caused by old version of mongoose
just update mongoose and it well be solved

```
npm install mongoose@latest
```